# Command tab switching to unexisting window

Tags: fullscreen, application-switcher

Command tab is not working properly anymore, it works pretty randomly.
If I switch several time between 2 fullscreen applications, sometimes it comes back to the desktop when no application is open, and I can see that the focus is on the application I wanted to switch on (from the top bar I can see the application name).

I already checked that: "when switching to an application, switch to the space with open windows for the application" is checked, but it still does not work. This is random, sometimes ok sometimes not

Comment: I frequently encounter this issue with Skype. It's due to how macOS considers an app to exist in one or more spaces, but the app in question is incorrectly reporting what spaces it currently resides on, so when you switch to that app, you end up on the wrong space. You can try to resolve this by right-clicking the app in the dock and trying out different values for the "Assign To [space]" option, but I don't have a guaranteed solution.

Comment: I don't have this option actually, witch version of max osx do you have please ? Mine is 10.14.6

Comment: I think that this option has been present since Yosemite (10.10), and definitely exists in Mojave (10.14), which is your version. I'm currently on Catalina (10.15), which is the latest. Are you running the app in native full-screen mode? What apps exhibit the issue?